# Cant crack OOP PHP chaining class->property->method

Tags: php, oop

after hours of trying and failing I here to ask for any help I can get. I am sure its simple for someone who knows OOP well but I just couldnt find any documentation to help me out with this and failed to solve it myself.

I have this code that I cannot change: **$woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency->get_currency_codes();**
And I need to create a class for it so it returns value of my choosing.

I know you can create class ($woocommerce_wpml = new xyClass;) and get its property ($woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency).

I know that you can create method within that class and run it ($woocommerce_wpml->get_currency_codes();)

I know you can chain methods but I just cannot figure out how to chain class->property->method. Or is it not a property and Im looking at it all wrong?

$woocommerce_wpml is class right?
multi_currency should be property right?
get_currency_codes() is method right?

How can I chain these (class->property->method)?

My failed code:

```
class testClass {
  public $multi_currency;
    function __construct($multi_currency) {
      $this->multi_currency = $multi_currency;
    }

  public function get_currency_codes() {
      return $this->multi_currency;
    }

}

$woocommerce_wpml = new testClass(["CZK","EUR"]);

var_dump( $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency); //array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "CZK" [1]=> string(3) "EUR" } 
var_dump($woocommerce_wpml->get_currency_codes()); //array(2) { [0]=> string(3) "CZK" [1]=> string(3) "EUR" }
echo $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency->get_currency_codes(); //Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_currency_codes() on array in ...
```

Comment: The answer from @Wakeel  below should help you understand the structure, That said, why do you think you `need to create a class for it so it returns value of my choosing`? If we understood your usage a bit better I'd bet we would suggest a more appropriate solution. Swapping out `$woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency` with a different object is likely to have more effects than just what `get_currency_codes()` returns unless you do it correctly.

Comment: I have a in wordpress plugin that checks for specific class (other plugin dependency) and if that class exists it asks for the $woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency->get_currency_codes() . Now I dont have that second plugin and I need to supply to the first plugin these arguments (fake class exists + properties) in order to enable some of its functionality

Comment: Fair enough, hopefully it doesnt require any other logic from that missing plugin, if not, thats somewhat workable. Generally speaking I'd lean towards adding the missing plugin or removing the dependency on it. Adding a custom class as the `multi_currency` could lead to unexpected behavior now or later. Imagine if later you add another plugin that also checks if  `$woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency` exists and sees it does then tries to call `$woocommerce_wpml->multi_currency->get_some_other_thing()` which would throw a fatal error. Something to consider anyway, happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An object property can be a reference to an object.

```
$myclass->property = new OtherClass();

echo $myclass->property->other_class_property;

//or access method 
$myclass->property->other_class_method();
```